# How to synchronize issues between SonarCloud and TFS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

I have a VSTS repo connect to SonarCloud for quality analysis.

I need unique issues source for my team.

When SonarCloud create issues in his system, I want create an equivalent issue in VSTS.
And, when the issue in VSTS closed by a commit, I want close SonarCloud issue.

Can you help ?

Same question with GitHub...

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Although there are issues created during an analysis in SonarCloud, the result is passed. So it won't create bug work item for such builds in VSTS.

The SonarCloud extension itself can not achieve what you want, one workaround here is using [SonarCloud api](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues) and [VSTS REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to implement your own solution.